# Cannot resolve @Value (Spring 4)

Tags: spring

I am trying to load different property files for different profiles.
I am running Tomcat 8.0, and using Spring 4.1.4.
In the xml I have defined my active profile like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In my spring configuration xml I have defined following profiles:

```
<beans profile="dev, default">
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:db_dev.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="qual">
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:db_qual.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In both properties file, I have defined following keys:

```
email.targetURL
email.from
```

The values are different for different profiles.

In my java Class i have the following fields:

```
@Value("${email.targetURL}")
String targetURL;
@Value("${email.from}")
String from;
```

When I run the application, value is not resolved, It simply prints out a string for example, "${email.from}".
The Class is a Spring Component and has also other autowired fields that are processed ok.

Any sugestions?

Comment: share the output you have after removing `<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>` from config.

Comment: Are you sure that property file exists and is accessible?

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond Removing the ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders makes no difference. The output is still the string "${email.from}".

Comment: @Mikhail Property exists but I'm not sure if it is accesible from java. I am loading the jdbc properties for different roles from the same property file in configuration xml, and from there it is accessible.